# Javascript best practice with .net Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have recently made a web application with C#, ASP, combined with some javascript. On my main page I have a mess of javascript/jQuery at the bottom with a series of ajax calls to web methods. Is there a way to break out this javascript into multiple js files to make my code more readable and purposed but still have access to the webmethods on the C# side?

Comment: What are you doing in C# with the web methods that you are accessing in JavaScript?

Comment: i am getting back some basic json data and then populating some controls with it.

Comment: How are you storing the JSON data and accessing it in C#?

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? Can you post your AJAX calls? It can be extracted into an external .js library, but if you're constructing your AJAX calls using Razor (ie: @Html.ActionLink(...)), then you will need to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the JavaScript page from your code and place them into .js files. To reference them, use the script tag

Comment: can i still make calls to the C# webmethods then? and can i minify this js file in a bundle?

Comment: Depends on how you're constructing your AJAX calls.

Comment: Yes as long as your webmethods are exposed, you can access them via javascript. You can minify the files and bundle them. I would wait until you are ready for producion because it will be hard to debug